# Finding out if a sum series converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've trying to figure a way to block/rearrange the equation such that I am able to use one of the tests (We havent been taught all of the tests yet, so far we're on positive series/sums).

The equation I'm trying to find weather it is diverging/converging is:

$$
\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{cos(\frac{\pi*n}{2})}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}
$$

I've tried blocking it from above with: $$\frac{1}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}$$

Yet the second series diverges, so it tells me not too much about the original series.

Any ideas/hints would be happily accepted.
Thanks!

Comment: Vocabulary: not "block", but "bound"

Answer (score 0):

$\cos (\frac {n \pi} 2)=0$ if $n$ is odd and $\cos (\frac {n \pi} 2)=(-1)^{n/2}$  if $n$ is even. It remains to show that $\sum \frac {(-1)^{m}} {(2m)(2m)^{1/(2m)}}$ is convergent.  Now use Alternating Series Test to show that the series is convergent.

Details: Let us show that $(x)(x^{1/x})$ is increasing: It is enough to show that $(\frac  1 x+1) \ln x$ is increasing on $[1,\infty)$. [ For, then, the exponential of this function would also be increasing]. Now, the derivative of $(\frac  1 x+1) \ln x$ is $-\frac  1 {x^{2}} \ln x+\frac 1  x+\frac 1 {x^{2}}$. Using the inequality $\ln x \leq x-1$  we see that $-\frac  1 {x^{2}} \ln x+\frac 1  x+\frac 1 {x^{2}} \geq \frac2 {x^{2}} \geq 0$. This proves our claim. It follows that $\frac 1{(2n)(2n)^{1/(2n)}}$ is decreasing and tends to $0$ as $ n \to \infty$. Now you are ready to apply the Alternating Series Test.

Comment: can you please elaborate? I've never used the Alternating Series Test before (haven't been taught that yet in the course) and I'm not sure how to apply it.

Comment: @Aishgadol I have added details of the proof. Let me know if you need further help.